# How to resolve CORS Policy error in Flask Framwork?

Tags: python, php

I have a Wordpress plugin. There is a form in the plugin's index.php file. I want to send this form data to my article.py file in pythonanywhere, save it here and then send a response to index.php. But I think I'm doing something wrong somewhere. I've been trying for about 12 hours but I can't do it. I'm not very knowledgeable about these issues. I will write the codes I use below. I keep getting CORS Policy error and I have read all forum pages and documents about it.

Here's the error I'm getting:

> Access to fetch at 'https://metehanz.pythonanywhere.com/submit' from
> origin 'http://deneme.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

When I run the article.py file I installed, I get the error "flask_cors no module named". So I deleted the .virtualenvs/ file and reinstalled it, activated it and entered the file path of the virtual environment in the Virtualenv section of the web panel (/home/metehanz/.virtualenvs/myenv). But the error persists. So I thought I might have installed article.py in the wrong place, so I deleted it and installed it next to flask_app.py, but the error persists.

First, the data sending codes in index.php:

```
fetch("http://username.pythonanywhere.com/submit", {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: formData
                    })
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                            }
                            return response.text();
                        })
                        .then(data => {
                            console.log(data);
                            // Başarılı cevap alındığında yapılacak işlemler buraya eklenebilir
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
                        });
```

Now I'm going to write the code in the article.py file. Don't worry, I installed things like flask_cors with the pip install command. But when I run the file on the site, I get the error "flask_cors no module named".

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Tüm kaynaklara erişime izin verir

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit_data():
    1_key = request.form.get('one')
    2_key = request.form.get('two')
    3_key = request.form.get('three')

    # Burada gelen verileri işleyin ve gerektiğinde yanıt döndürün

    return 'Veriler başarıyla alındı.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8081)  # veya başka bir port numarası seçebilirsiniz
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm just asking what could be the problem, I've tried almost all the methods to fix the CORS Policy error, but it's probably not working for the simple reason that the file is in a different directory. I would like to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can narrow down your problem by testing this one-line python file:

```
import flask_cors
```

I suspect you'll find that the python running your flask script does not see the `flask_cors` module that you installed. It's a common problem. Think about the different environments or different Python executables that you have, and provide more information about these if you need help. (It's likely that "Don't worry, I installed things like flask_cors with the pip install command." does not tell the whole story, otherwise you would not have a question here.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow access to your Flask app from `http://deneme.local`.  You would do that by changing this line:

```
CORS(app)
```

...to this:

```
CORS(app, origins=[“http://deneme.local”, "https://deneme.local"])
```

Comment: I did this and refreshed the page. When I tried to send data again, I got the same error.

Comment: I don't know if I need to edit the Pythonanywhere admin panel or files like wsgi.py, flask_app.py, etc. I didn't change any settings, I just created a virtual environment in the bash console, installed flask_cors and uploaded my own article.py file and tried to operate there.

Comment: Did you reload the website using the button on the "Web" page after making the code change?